# Is it possible to access data within a table in a dedicated SQL pool in Azure Synapse using REST API endpoints?

Tags: azure, rest, azure-synapse

I am trying to see whether it is possible to access some data stored within a table in a dedicated SQL in Azure Synapse using REST API but I have not been able to figure much out. I checked the official docs at Microsoft and at most I have been able to query for a specific column within a table, not much more beyond that. I am wondering whether it is even possible to get data through the Azure Synapse REST API. Would appreciate any help.

Docs for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access the data in Synapse Dedicated SQL pools using REST APIs, today it is possible only to manage compute using REST API.